# blockui() and unblockUi() in ajax

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

```
    $.blockUI();
    email = $("#txtregistEmail").val();
    chaptch = $("#txtregistcaptcha").val();

    var result = "";
    result = $.ajax({ url: "AllCommand.aspx?cmd=InsertMember&txtregistEmail=" + email + "&txtregistcaptcha=" + chaptch ,
        async: false,
        complete: function () {
            // unblock when remote call returns 
           $.unblockUI();
        }
    }).responseText; ;
```

this code run success  but Does not work blockui() and unblockui()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $.blockUI({
            message: '<b><img src="/images/IconLoading.gif" /> در حال انجام عملیات...</b>',
            css: {
                border: 'none',
                padding: '15px',
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                opacity: .5,
                color: '#fff',
                width: '200px'
            }
        });
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $.unblockUI();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the **'s in your actual code? If so, that's why the calls aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same problem as this: [blockUI vs ajax with async option to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009223/blockui-vs-ajax-with-async-option-to-false) (possible duplicate!).

You have to set async to true and all the code that you want to execute after you ajax call has to be called inside "success", e.g.